# replace the index null value by the prevous index in while loop using PHP

Tags: php

I have tried the PHP code as below:

```
$i=1;
foreach(getTop5($pid) as $da){
    $i++                
    if($da['index_enjeu_percu'] != NULL){
      foreach(getDataChart($pid,$da['index_enjeu_percu']) as $data){
        $avg = $data["avg_index_importance"].', ';

        $poin_important = substr($avg,0,-2);
        $enjeu .= $data["index_enjeu"].', ';
        $res_enjeu = substr($enjeu,0,-1);
        echo $avg;
        }
    }
    else{
        // I want to do the foreach again in here but my data $da['index_enjeu_percu'] == NUll
        //I don want to take it as NULL value, I want to take the prevous value of $da['index_enjeu_percu']
        foreach(getDataChart($pid,$da['index_enjeu_percu']) as $data){
            $avg = $data["avg_index_importance"].', ';

            $poin_important = substr($avg,0,-2);
            $enjeu .= $data["index_enjeu"].', ';
            $res_enjeu = substr($enjeu,0,-1);
            echo $avg;
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is that : I have loop data as above 
        Ex: if my result is that: `1 2 3 4  NULL` in case  it equal `NULL` I want to replace `NULL` with `4`
        I don have the solution for this. Any one help me please, thanks

Comment: Why are you not using `$i` anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the previous value to a session try like this:

```
session_start();
$i=1;
foreach(getTop5($pid) as $da){
    $i++;                
    if($da['index_enjeu_percu'] != NULL){
      $_SESSION['prev_value']=$da['index_enjeu_percu']; // This will save the value of da['index_enjeu_percu'] to session
      foreach(getDataChart($pid,$da['index_enjeu_percu']) as $data){
        $avg = $data["avg_index_importance"].', ';

        $poin_important = substr($avg,0,-2);
        $enjeu .= $data["index_enjeu"].', ';
        $res_enjeu = substr($enjeu,0,-1);
        echo $avg;
        }
    }
    else{
        $da['index_enjeu_percu'] = $_SESSION['prev_value']; // This will get the previous value of index
        foreach(getDataChart($pid,$da['index_enjeu_percu']) as $data){
            $avg = $data["avg_index_importance"].', ';

            $poin_important = substr($avg,0,-2);
            $enjeu .= $data["index_enjeu"].', ';
            $res_enjeu = substr($enjeu,0,-1);
            echo $avg;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep Last value in a variable. Check if $avg is null then print previous number else print $avg.

```
$i=1;
$prev_avg = NULL;
foreach(getTop5($pid) as $da){
    $i++                
    if($da['index_enjeu_percu'] != NULL){
      foreach(getDataChart($pid,$da['index_enjeu_percu']) as $data){
        $avg = $data["avg_index_importance"].', ';

        $poin_important = substr($avg,0,-2);
        $enjeu .= $data["index_enjeu"].', ';
        $res_enjeu = substr($enjeu,0,-1);
        if ($avg == NULL)
            echo $prev_avg;
        else
            echo $avg;
        $prev_avg = $avg;
        }
    }
    else{
        // I want to do the foreach again in here but my data $da['index_enjeu_percu'] == NUll
        //I don want to take it as NULL value, I want to take the prevous value of $da['index_enjeu_percu']
        foreach(getDataChart($pid,$da['index_enjeu_percu']) as $data){
            $avg = $data["avg_index_importance"].', ';

            $poin_important = substr($avg,0,-2);
            $enjeu .= $data["index_enjeu"].', ';
            $res_enjeu = substr($enjeu,0,-1);
        if ($avg == NULL)
            echo $prev_avg;
        else
            echo $avg;
        $prev_avg = $avg;

        }
    }
}
```